# Does this notation mean a set, product, or $X$-indexed family? - Category Theory

Tags: category-theory, notation

From Mac Lane's Category theory:

In the first red box, does $\{fi_x | x \in X\}$ represent a set of all maps $fi_x$, the product of maps $\langle fi_x \rangle_{x \in X}$ (as in the bijection in the box below), or an $X$-indexed family (as in the definition of $X$-fold coproduct)?

[image]

Comment: I don't understand your second and third options.  I would think $\langle fi_x\rangle_{x\in X}$ is an "$X$-indexed family", not a "product of maps".  Can you explain what your definitions of "$X$-indexed family" and "product of maps" are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> does $\{fi_x | x \in X\}$ represent a set of all maps $fi_x$,

No, not the set of all maps. I think it's a mistake in the notation.

> the product of maps $\langle fi_x \rangle_{x \in X}$ (as in the bijection in the box below),

Yes, this. An element of $\prod_{x\in X}C(a_x,c)$

> or an $X$-indexed family (as in the definition of $X$-fold coproduct)?

An $X$-indexed family is the same thing as a product. $C^X\cong\prod_{x\in X}C.$ So yes. As an $X$-indexed family, you may think of it as an arrow in $C^X.$ Then it is the arrow $a\to \Delta c.$ But I would say answer 2 above is the "right" answer, as the notation implies a product of sets.

But you could also write it using a more functional notation, as

$$
C(\coprod_x F(x),c)\cong C^X(F,\Delta(c)).
$$

With this notation, it's more clearly option 3. This also makes clear that colimit functors are left adjoints of the diagonal functor (all colimits, not just coproducts), which is nice to know.

Answer (score 0):

Given the set `X`, let  be the category with objects-collection `X` --the set we were given-- and morphism-collection being `{idₓ ∣ x ∈ X}` to be just the identities on the “objects”. ( I.e., we are construing a set X as a category. )

A functor  `⟶`  assigns to each object `x : Obj`  an object, call it,
`aₓ : Obj` . Moreover, it preserves identities and ``morphism typing'', but
by definition of  there are only identities and so such a mapping is determined by its restriction to `Obj  ⟶ Obj` , but `Obj  = X` by definition,
and so a functor  `⟶`  is nothing more than a family of objects of 
indexed by the set `X`, i.e., a function `a : X ⟶ Obj` .

Let us write `s ⟶ t` in-place of `(s, t)`, then your displayed formula says
`(⊔ₓ aₓ ⟶ c) ≅ Πₓ (aₓ ⟶ c)` where `x` ranges over `X`.

This bijection says that a morphism from the “union” `⊔ₓ aₓ` to some target object `c` *must* consider each component of the union: Each `x` is a possibility that must be accounted-for, and so it is essentially the same as a product of all
such considerations.

The bijection is formally witnessed by assigning a function `f : ⊔ₓ aₓ ⟶ c`
into a function `f́ : Πₓ (aₓ ⟶ c)`. By definition of products `f́` is characterised “component functions” and so at “component `x`” we shall produce a map typed `aₓ ⟶ c`. By merely matching types we are inexorably led to take `aₓ` and `inj`ect it into the coproduct `⊔ₓ aₓ` then use the given `f` to reach `c`. Whence, `f́ = ⟨ f ∘ injₓ ∣ x ∈ X⟩`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: If you interpret the arrow as implication and the coproduct as disjunction, then the displayed formula here is the classical result that *implications over disjunctions are conjunctions of implications*.  Alternatively, ``an existence implies something is the same as a universal whose components imply that thing''.